# React hook form: How to use onChange on React Hook Form for react-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-select

Im using react hook form for few fields with validation, and I need to change second by changing first, for example, I want to change dataBit to undefined and delete required if DataType !== DataType._1, and it work partly

I use state for required and isDisabled check:

```
const [dataType, setDataType] = useState<DataType>()
```

Function for change DataType:

```
function onChangeData(dataTypeValue: DataType) {
   setValue("dataType", dataTypeValue)
   setDataType(dataTypeValue)
   if (dataTypeValue !== DataType._1) {
   setValue("dataBit", undefined)
  //**here I have getValues("dataBit") = undefined**
})}
```

but after click onSubmit I have previos selected value on data.dataBit, and in select I see previos value, not "-"

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FunctionDTO> = async (data) => {
//previos selected value on data.dataBit
}
```

my selects description:

```
                <Controller
                    name={"dataType"}
                    control={control}
                    rules={{ required: intl.formatMessage({id: 'input_required' }) }}
                    render={({ field: {value, onChange, name, ref, } }) => (
                        <Select
                            name={name}
                            ref={ref}
                            options={optionsDataType}
                            styles={customStyles}
                            isDisabled={props.isDisabledFunction}
                            onChange={(value) => {onChangeData(value?.value!) }}
                            value={optionsDataType.find(
                                (option) =>
                                    option.value === value
                            )}
                        />
                    )}
                />
              <Controller
                  name={"dataBit"}
                  control={control}
                  rules={{
                    required:
                        dataType === DataType._1
                            ? intl.formatMessage({id: 'input_required' })
                            : false,
                  }}
                  render={({ field: {value, name, onChange, ref } }) => (
                      <Select
                          name={name}
                          ref={ref}
                          options={optionsDataBit}
                          styles={customStyles}
                          isDisabled={
                              props.isDisabledFunction ||
                              dataType !== DataType._1
                          }
                          onChange={(val) => {onChange(val?.value)}}
                          value={optionsDataBit.find(
                              (option) => option.value === value
                          )}
                      />
                  )}
              />
```

select options

```
export const optionsDataType = [
 { label: "bit", value: DataType._1 },
 { label: "byte", value: DataType._2 },
 { label: "2-Byte", value: DataType._3 },
];

export const optionsDataBit = [
 { label: "-", value: undefined },
 { label: "0", value: 0 },
 { label: "1", value: 1 },
 { label: "2", value: 2 },
 { label: "3", value: 3 },
 { label: "4", value: 4 },
 { label: "5", value: 5 },
 { label: "6", value: 6 },
 { label: "7", value: 7 },
];
```

Why dataBit is rolling back after I set value?